# Adding a "Pick from Photo Library" button to UIImagePickerController's toolbar

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am implementing a flow where the user can either select a photo from their library or take a photo using the camera.
When presenting the UIImagePickerController modally I have to either go:

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

or

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

This means presenting a "scaffolding controller" where to user can pick either their Library or the Camera.
I see that most other apps with this kind of functionality go directly to the Camera controller, but displays a button for selecting from the library instead.

All examples/tutorials I can find, including Apple's PhotoPicker source, does this empty viewController where you pick from camera or library - but all apps I check does the 'direct to camera - with the option for going to library".

**How do I add the photo library button option to the camera tool bar?**

(app >= iOS 4.3)

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this previous question

[Enabling the photo library button on the UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528880/enabling-the-photo-library-button-on-the-uiimagepickercontroller)

you can use cameraOverlayView and showsCameraControls to make the implementation.

-Vik

Answer (score 5):

For this purpose I have used [PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) by Apple.